# How to detect cookie in specific domains using $_COOKIE or any other way

Tags: php, cookies

Hi guys this is abit similer to a question that i posted earlier. but now i have found the problem which lies behind it...when i set a cookie using my script known as cookieset.php

```
setcookie("atid", 1234, time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 365, "/", ".mydomain.com");
```

and it is shown in the browser

```
Name    atid
Content 1234
domain  mydomain.com
```

in another instance i set a cookie in this way

```
setcookie('atid', '1234', time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 365, "/", "localhost");
```

and it is shown in the browser

```
Name    atid
Content 1234
domain  localhost
```

but when i try to retrieve it like this from another script

```
echo 'value is: ' . $_COOKIE['atid'];
```

the correct value is shown only when i create the cookie by giving the domain name as localhost, but when i give, my specific domain name `$_COOKIE['atid'];` does not detect the cookie but gives the error

```
undefnied index: atid in.........
```

can anybody help me to detect the cookie on my domain name

Comment: why whats wrong with the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cookies are stored on client side i.e. on the browser. Also cookies are domain specific, and sub-domains can access the cookies of parent domain.
e.g.: if you have created a cookie for domain test.com then www.test.com, demo.test.com etc can access that cookie.

The reason you're unable to access the cookie with the your domain name is because, probably you have created the cookie using localhost i.e. your second code
**setcookie('atid', '1234', time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 365, "/", "localhost");** and trying to access it from your domain name. remove localhost from above code and then try to access it from your domain name.

use this code:

```
setcookie('atid', '1234', time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 365, "/");
```

Let me know if the issue still persist.

Comment: thank you for the response, this creates the cookie again in localhost, the problem even if i create only the mydomain cookie, the $_COOKIE does not detect my cookie